# picker view - units conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm developing an application with a picker view that slide from the bottom (like an action sheet). I need to convert 3 units (litres, us gallons and imperial gallons). The value is taken from a  text field but I don't know how to tell the compiler which was the unit to start from.
(ie...the user insert the value in the the text field but if he changes the units (usg or ig), the value in the text field changes accordingly.

this is the array:

```
  NSMutableArray *weightArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"", @"Ltr",@"Usg",@"Ig",
                               nil];
self.weightPickerViewArray = weightArray;
[weightArray release];`
```

this is the picker:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
if (row == 1) {
    labelVolume.text = [weightPickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];

  //more code here....

}else if (row == 2){
    labelVolume.text = [weightPickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];

    //more code here....
}else if (row == 3){
    labelVolume.text = [weightPickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];

    //more code here....
```

}
how can I tell the compiler which was the value before the selection?

Comment: Well it is not clear..atleast to me..:(

Comment: @mattia still it is not understood

Comment: ok... let me try again. The default value is litres. For instance,  the user insert in the the text field 1000 litres. If the user push the button "change unit", a picker or an action sheet slide from the bottom giving 3 options: litres, us gallons and imperial gallons. when the user selects us gallons the value in the text field change from 1000 L to 264.17 usg.

Comment: @mattia ok now it is clear,so what is the problem ,what you want to do when the picker slides up?

Comment: when the picker slides up the  user can select 3 different units: Litres, Us gallons or Imperial gallons. when one of the units is selected there is a label (beside a text field)that change into Ltr, Usg or Ig. Everything works perfect until now. I also want to take the value in the text field to convert it into the unit selected by the user. i'm gonna post my code....;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a text indicating the units at the end of the string.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
if (row == 1) {
    NSString *initalValue = labelVolume.text;
    // Do your calculations here based on unit
    NSString *updatedValue = urNewValue;
    labelVolume.text = updatedValue;

  //more code here....

}else if (row == 2){
NSString *initalValue = labelVolume.text;
    // Do your calculations here based on unit
    NSString *updatedValue = urNewValue;
    labelVolume.text = updatedValue;


    //more code here....
}else if (row == 3){
NSString *initalValue = labelVolume.text;
    // Do your calculations here based on unit
    NSString *updatedValue = urNewValue;
    labelVolume.text = updatedValue;


    //more code here....
}
```

Comment: I need to know which was the unit before the new selection to make the right calculation. Ie ....if it was litres and the user selected usgallons I have to multiply for 0.264172052 but it was imperialgallons and the user selected us gallons I have to multiply for 1.20095042. how can I do it?

Comment: Assign the units to the end of the string in the text field delegate methods initially. Then update them based on the converted ones.

Answer (score 0):

When you select a row in picker, it call's its delegate method pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
Here, you can can change the value of your text field depending on which row (liters, gallons, etc) user selected.
Please refer the apple's class reference for UIPickerView delegate

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem. You want catch event when user change units in your pickerView, pass the information to the view that contains text field and execute conversion.

So you can use NSNotificationCenter [(documentation here)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In your pickerView when value change put this code :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"unitValueChange" object:@"litres"];
```

In the view that contains UITextField put this code :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethodToExecute:) name:@"unitValueChange" object:self];
```

Now when your PickerView launch notification your view launch this method :

```
-(void)myMethodToExecute:(NSNotification *)notif{
NSString *myUnitSelected = notif.object
}
```

Comment: it helps me but I need to study a little bit. The problem is that I need to tell the compiler which was the unit before the user selection otherwise I'm not able to write the code to make the calculation.